# MIPS Adding all elements from array

Tags: assembly, mips

I am new to MIPS and learning the basics.  I have ran into a problem I have been working on for two hours and have no luck.  I tried to search this problem online but there is very limited samples.  So basically I am writing two functions:

1. Summation of an array. For my summation function always outputs 268501055 for a simple array.  I feel as if my logic is correct but no luck in finding the error. I have this function named sumArray.
2. Finding max of an array. I receive exception 4 followed by unlimited exception 7 error messages when running.  I'm not sure why it is not working.  I am using QTSpim simulator to run these tests.

Here below is my code:

```
##
    .data

    A: .word 11, 12, -10, 13, 9, 12, 14, 15, -20, 0 
    out_m: .asciiz "The maximum of A is : "
    out_s: .asciiz "The summation of A is : "
    out_n: .asciiz "\n"

    .text

main:
    la $a3, A 

    jal sumArray 

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, out_n 
    syscall

    jal findMax 

    li $v0, 10  
    syscall

findMax:

    add $t0, $zero, $a3 
    lw $t8, ($t0) 
    addi $t1, $zero, 0
    add $t3, $zero, $a0 
    L1: slti $t2, $t1, 10
        beq $t2, $zero, Loop2 
        lw $t4, 0($t3) 
        addi $t3, $t3, 4 
        slt $t2, $t0, $t4                       
        addi $t1, $zero, 1
        beq $t2, $zero, Loop3

        j L1
    Loop3: add $t8, $zero, $t4
        j L1
    Loop2: li $v0, 4
    la $a0, out_m
    syscall

    move $t3, $v0
    li $v0, 1
    move $a1, $t0
    syscall

    jr $ra

sumArray:

    addi $t0, $zero, 0
    addi $t6, $zero, 0
    add $t5, $zero, $zero
    loop: slti $t1, $t0, 9
        add $t2, $a3, $t6
        beq $t1, $zero, $L
        lw $t4, 0($t2)
        add $t5, $t5, $t4
        addi $t0, $t0, 1
        addi $t6, $t6,4
        j loop
    $L:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, out_s
    syscall

    move $t5, $v0
    li $v0, 1
    move $a1, $t0
    syscall

    jr $ra


## end of file
```

Sorry for the messy code, I tried to format appropriately. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: QtSpim comes with a debugger. You can use it to step through your code line by line to see where your mistake is.

Comment: _" I'm not sure why it is not working"_. The simulator told you why: `lw $t4, 0($t3)` is trying to read from an invalid address.